# Nancy maximum JSON length exception when Binding

Tags: c#, json, nancy

I have simple Nancy self hosting C# project which deserializes data in NancyModule like this:

```
Post["/build"] = (something) => { var data = this.Bind<Brick>(); }
```

I am getting "Maximum JSON input length has been exceeded." when Request.Body.Length is close to 2MB. I would like to send tens of megabytes of data in the future and 2MB is just too low. Can I remove this limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can override the MaxJsonLength and the MaxRecursions. Basically I did a custom bootstrapper something like this:

```
public class CustomBootStrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
        {
            Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.MaxRecursions = 100;
            Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.RetainCasing = true;
            base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I implemented this the dumb way. Instead of overriding bootstrapper and trying to understand why I have to do this I just change limits in the constructor of the service.

Answer (score 2):

For me Nancy didn't work all together even after applying below settings. As my data was really really huge.

```
  Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
```

I ended up using Json.net (add via nuGet package)

```
  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```