# Nancy: configure per-request MaxJsonLength and other json serialization settings

Tags: c#, json, serialization, nancy, json-serialization

I would like Nancy's Json serialization to behave as usual for a certain set of requests.
For other (very particular!) requests, usually for diagnostic purpose, I'd like to be able to get very specific settings, such as MaxJsonLength set to int.MaxValue.

The only way I found to change the default behavior is to set the static value of Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.MaxJsonLength (as described, for example, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046722/1288109 ). The drawback of this solution is that the setting is applied to all calls (something I'd like to avoid!).
(I also would like to avoid "dirty" tricks such as temporary change the values of Nancy.Json.JsonSettings, restore them at the end of the call and invent weird fancy stuff to prevent unexpected behaviors for calls processed at the same time)

So: is it possible to change Nancy's Json serialization settings PER-REQUEST? How?